# Make observable arrays created via ko.mapping.fromJS not have observable elements

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Observable arrays created using ko.mapping.fromJS() have observable elements. How can I make it behave more like ko.observableArray() where the array is observable but the elements of the array are not? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, not to be a smart ass but have you considered just not using the mapping plugin for that leg of your model?  That is like the main intended purpose of the plugin.

Comment: Hi PW. Thanks for the response. I have considered this but the viewmodel is somewhat large (more than just this array) and it would be a pain to explicitly map out the observable. At very worst this is an option but if there is an easier way I'd like to know.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, perhaps add some code with what you tried or wanted to write, add a few details on *why* you'd want this, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mapping plugin create option. From the ko docs (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

```
// The data to be mapped
var data = {
    name: 'Graham',
    children: [
        { id : 1, name : 'Lisa' }
    ]
};

// Your custom data model
var myChildModel = function (data) {
    this.id = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;
};

var mapping = {
    'children': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new myChildModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

From this example the 'children' array will be mapped like an observable array, where the properties are not observables.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for not reading the documentation well enough before posting.

Comment: Np, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var model = ko.observableArray(ko.toJS(data));
```

This will make the top level elements into observableArrays, but the child arrays will remain plain arrays and not observable. I am not sure if this is desirable to you or not.

Comment: Hi Hitezh. Are you saying to manually assign the property to an observableArray after calling ko.mapping.fromJS()?

Comment: The above code will only make an observableArray, i.e. you can 'observe' objects getting added & removed from the array. If you want **two-way** binding of the properties of the objects in the array, this will not work.